# How to traverse forward and backwards in NSBrowser?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsbrowser

I am trying to create something similar to the OS X finder.

How can I go backwards and forwards like in OS X finder? I'm not sure which methods to call to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the user clicks to navigate. To do it programmatically, you probably want `-setSelectionIndexPath:`